# How to hide POST form in Django REST framework?

Tags: django

I have Django REST framework form like this:

[image]

and I would like to do a simple thing: hide POST form (in the red rectangle) when the user is not logged in. I just don't know how to do it, because all I have is model, view that inherits from ListCreateAPIView and serializer inhgeriting from ModelSerializer.

Comment: Does [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly) help here?

Comment: @Melvyn A lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django rest framework Authentication and Permission classes: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: I was looking for exactly something like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
```

if you use generic or viewsets class add this line inside your view class

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

or you can set permission to admins only by import

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser
```

and

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```